# ReplayKit 2 didn't show my app when start broadcasting from my app or from system

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I'm new to iOS programming.
I'm trying to write an app for screen broadcasting/recording.

Follow the guide of [WWDC2018](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/601).
1. new target of "Broadcast Upload Extension" and "Broadcast Setup UI Extension".
   Note: neither SampleHandler.swift nor BroadcastSetupViewController.swift is modified.
2. modify the ViewController.swift as following

```
import UIKit
import ReplayKit

@available(iOS 12.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var broadcastPicker: RPSystemBroadcastPickerView?

    var broadcastPicker: RPSystemBroadcastPickerView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            let broadcastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                    width: view.bounds.width, height: 500))
            broadcastPicker.preferredExtension = "com.myapp.extension"
            view.addSubview(broadcastPicker)        
    }
}
```

After installation, when pressing the app to start broadcasting, following screen is shown. There is no icon of my app. The preferredExtension is confirmed correct as the extension's Bundle Identifier.
[image: Start broadcasting in app]

If starting broadcast from the system, there are many provider options, but not my app.
[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 6):

If your app extension is not visible in PickerView as well as in Control Center, it means that the extension is not installed. Check out the deployment Info in the general section of the Xcode project's target. In my case, I had the same experience when the iOS version of the device was lower than the deployment target version.

Comment: The iphone to install is iOS 13.4.1.
And the target version is 12.

Comment: Hi 

I am facing the same issue. Kindly help me how you install extension.

Comment: Thanks its fixed, But now I am not getting loaded my broadcast extension class